# cloning from Azure Devops GIT- HTTP 407 Proxy Authorization Required

Tags: git, intellij-idea, plugins, clone

When i tried to clone the code from

1. IntelliJ>Getfrom Version Control>Azure Devops GIt>clone>Authentication>
   and i am getting the following error:

```
getAuthenticationInfoAsync failed

com.microsoft.alm.client.model.VssResourceNotFoundException: 
API resource location f83745dc-483f-4228-a291-d45f6080a9af is not registered 
on https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com. HTTP 407 Proxy Authorization Required
```

I am using uptodate version of IDE and Azure Devops plugin. and i have also provided the proxy details inside my IDE.

Can you please advice how i can get through this.